# How can I unit test optional route parameters for an Angular resolver

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-router

I'm trying to unit test optional route parameters for an Angular 7 resolver but can only get it to work when a parameter is provided.

The code below is working, but I want to test a scenario where an id is not provided (the user navigates to `incident`, not `incident/12345`)

How can I achieve this in my unit test?

My routes are setup like this in my routing module:

```
{
    path: 'incident',
    component: IncidentComponent,
    resolve: {
        rescue: RescueResolver
    }
},
{
    path: 'incident/:id',
    component: IncidentComponent,
    resolve: {
        rescue: RescueResolver
    }
},
```

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute, convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';

import { RescueResolver } from '@core/resolvers';
import { RescueService } from '@core/services';

fdescribe('RescueResolver', () => {
    let resolver: RescueResolver;
    let service: RescueService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [
                RescueResolver,
                RescueService,
                {
                    provide: ActivatedRoute,
                    useValue: {
                        snapshot: {
                            paramMap: convertToParamMap({
                                id: '1'
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }));

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        resolver = TestBed.get(RescueResolver);
        service = TestBed.get(RescueService);
    }));

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(resolver).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should call getRescue when an id has been passed as a parameter', () => {
        spyOn(service, 'getRescue');
        resolver.resolve();
        expect(service.getRescue).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1');
    });
});
```